# JavaScript Sqlite - Simple way of storing single result in a var

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I've been trying to store a single row result (in this case being ID) in a variable, so that it can be used elsewhere. I've got the following, but it's not passing it through.

```
    var muteid =
con.each("SELECT max(id) as id from full_track", function(err, row) {
  console.log(row.id);
});

const logembed = new discord.RichEmbed()
//.setTitle("User Muted")
  .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
  .setDescription(`${tomute.user.tag} has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutedtime))}`)
  .addField(`**Reason:** ${mutedreason}`, `aa`)
  .setFooter(`ID: ${muteid}`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setColor(3447003)
```

Comment: What does "it's not passing it through" mean?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: var muteid is simply undefined - the console.log will return the correct result however

Comment: Can you provide more context? Where are you defining this variable? Sounds like it's in a different scope than where you're trying to use it.

Comment: Updated my original query

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your code into your `con.each` handler where you put the console.log

```
var muteid, logembed = [];

con.each("SELECT max(id) as id from full_track", function(err, row) {
  console.log(row.id);
  muteid = row.id;

  logembed[muteid] = new discord.RichEmbed()
  //.setTitle("User Muted")
    .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
    .setDescription(`${tomute.user.tag} has been muted for ${ms(ms(mutedtime))}`)
    .addField(`**Reason:** ${mutedreason}`, `aa`)
    .setFooter(`ID: ${muteid}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(3447003);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I expose the muteid to code outside of the con.each handler?

Comment: It should stay accessible outside the scope of the function (it is declared outside).